# Apache Druid segment merge task submition failure

Tags: apache, merge, task, segment, druid

I am using Druid 0.9.1.1 and trying to merge all the segment of a datasource per day to a single segment. Whereas the merge task initiation fails with error :

```
{"error":"Instantiation of [simple type, class io.druid.timeline.DataSegment] value failed: null (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])"}
```

I have got the segment details from segment metadata query. There is no help from driud documents as only specify raw structure of the overall query, but not the required segment detail structure(Below is how druid document suggests).

```
{
"type": "merge",
"id": <task_id>,
"dataSource": <task_datasource>,
"aggregations": <list of aggregators>,
"segments": <JSON list of DataSegment objects to merge>
```

}

example queries :

```
{
"type": "merge",
"id": "envoy_merge_task",
"dataSource": "dcap.envoy.diskmounts.kafka",
"segments": [{"id":"dcap.sermon.threshold.kafka_2017-05-22T00:00:00.000Z_2017-05-23T00:00:00.000Z_2017-05-22T07:00:02.951Z","intervals":["2017-05-22T00:00:00.000Z/2017-05-23T00:00:00.000Z"],"columns":{},"size":5460959,"numRows":41577,"aggregators":null,"queryGranularity":null},{"id":"dcap.sermon.threshold.kafka_2017-05-22T00:00:00.000Z_2017-05-23T00:00:00.000Z_2017-05-22T07:00:02.951Z_1","intervals":["2017-05-22T00:00:00.000Z/2017-05-23T00:00:00.000Z"],"columns":{},"size":5448881,"numRows":41577,"aggregators":null,"queryGranularity":null},{"id":"dcap.sermon.threshold.kafka_2017-05-22T00:00:00.000Z_2017-05-23T00:00:00.000Z_2017-05-22T07:00:02.951Z_2","intervals":["2017-05-22T00:00:00.000Z/2017-05-23T00:00:00.000Z"],"columns":{},"size":5454452,"numRows":41571,"aggregators":null,"queryGranularity":null},{"id":"dcap.sermon.threshold.kafka_2017-05-22T00:00:00.000Z_2017-05-23T00:00:00.000Z_2017-05-22T07:00:02.951Z_3","intervals":["2017-05-22T00:00:00.000Z/2017-05-23T00:00:00.000Z"],"columns":{},"size":5456267,"numRows":41569,"aggregators":null,"queryGranularity":null}] }
```

I have tried different forms of structure for "segments" key, results in same error.

example :

```
"segments": [{"id":"dcap.envoy.diskmounts.kafka_2017-05-21T06:00:00.000Z_2017-05-21T07:00:00.000Z_2017-05-21T06:02:43.482Z"},{"id":"dcap.envoy.diskmounts.kafka_2017-05-21T06:00:00.000Z_2017-05-21T07:00:00.000Z_2017-05-21T06:02:43.482Z_1"},{"id":"dcap.envoy.diskmounts.kafka_2017-05-21T06:00:00.000Z_2017-05-21T07:00:00.000Z_2017-05-21T06:02:43.482Z_2"},{"id":"dcap.envoy.diskmounts.kafka_2017-05-21T06:00:00.000Z_2017-05-21T07:00:00.000Z_2017-05-21T06:02:43.482Z_3"}]
```

What is right structure for segment-merge tasks.

Comment: [IndexTask improvements](https://github.com/druid-io/druid/pull/3611) .. Druid contributors are working on it.

Answer (score -1):

the format i used for segments is

```
    "segments":[
        {
            "dataSource": "wikiticker88",
            "interval": "2015-09-12T02:00:00.000Z/2015-09-12T03:00:00.000Z",
            "version": "2018-01-16T07:23:16.425Z",
            "loadSpec": {
                "type": "local",
                "path": "/home/linux/druid-0.11.0/var/druid/segments/wikiticker88/2015-09-12T02:00:00.000Z_2015-09-12T03:00:00.000Z/2018-01-16T07:23:16.425Z/0/index.zip"
            },
            "dimensions": "channel,cityName,comment,countryIsoCode,countryName,isAnonymous,isMinor,isNew,isRobot,isUnpatrolled,metroCode,namespace,page,regionIsoCode,regionName,user",
            "metrics": "count,added,deleted,delta,user_unique",
            "shardSpec": {
                "type": "none"
            },
            "binaryVersion": 9,
            "size": 198267,
            "identifier": "wikiticker88_2015-09-12T02:00:00.000Z_2015-09-12T03:00:00.000Z_2018-01-16T07:23:16.425Z"
        },
]
```

use this to get your metadata of segments

```
/druid/coordinator/v1/metadata/datasources/{dataSourceName}/segments?full
```